# Tkinter pyplot subplot using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a dataframe with various values in and am trying to plot it onto a figure embedded into tkinter. Here is the code:

```
figure = plt.Figure(figsize=((0.8 / 3) * res_width / 100, 0.2 * res_height / 100), facecolor="#67676b")    
figure.add_subplot(fc="#15151c").plot(df["Close time"][0:50], df["Close"][0:50], "-g")
```

Here is what is shown:
[image]

It shows a straight line, why is this, when the data clearly shows otherwise?
I ouputted Close axis as a list and here is the output:

```
['19183.62000000', '19184.58000000', '19185.57000000', '19183.94000000', '19202.16000000', '19213.30000000', '19199.25000000', '19176.14000000', '19186.30000000', '19179.88000000', '19179.34000000', '19178.32000000', '19187.08000000', '19181.12000000', '19200.12000000', '19202.25000000', '19209.05000000', '19208.59000000', '19200.92000000', '19205.37000000', '19205.23000000', '19205.19000000', '19200.26000000', '19199.92000000', '19198.12000000', '19200.99000000', '19204.54000000', '19210.29000000', '19210.00000000', '19209.86000000', '19219.52000000', '19222.24000000', '19253.65000000', '19241.24000000', '19255.85000000', '19257.37000000', '19250.00000000', '19239.38000000', '19236.97000000', '19246.57000000', '19230.70000000', '19229.76000000', '19228.76000000', '19229.75000000', '19231.22000000', '19227.77000000', '19229.69000000', '19209.75000000', '19211.64000000', '19232.56000000']
```

As you can see, the graph should go up and down and not just a straight line. Is it only plotting a trend line for some reason?

I recreated a "minimal reproducible example":

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import sys

platform = sys.platform


# root class
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        # cycle through windows
        for F in (MainMenu, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(MainMenu)

    # method to change frames
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):  # main menu
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg="#15151c")

        close_time = [1605549599999, 1605553199999, 1605556799999, 1605560399999, 1605563999999, 1605567599999, 1605571199999, 1605574799999, 1605578399999, 1605581999999, 1605585599999, 1605589199999, 1605592799999, 1605596399999, 1605599999999, 1605603599999, 1605607199999, 1605610799999, 1605614399999, 1605617999999, 1605621599999, 1605625199999, 1605628799999, 1605632399999, 1605635999999, 1605639599999, 1605643199999, 1605646799999, 1605650399999, 1605653999999, 1605657599999, 1605661199999, 1605664799999, 1605668399999, 1605671999999, 1605675599999, 1605679199999, 1605682799999, 1605686399999, 1605689999999, 1605693599999, 1605697199999, 1605700799999, 1605704399999, 1605707999999, 1605711599999, 1605715199999, 1605718799999, 1605722399999, 1605725999999]
        close = ['16691.91000000', '16690.85000000', '16779.01000000', '16825.56000000', '16695.41000000', '16713.86000000', '16713.57000000', '16806.09000000', '16690.21000000', '16678.02000000', '16573.58000000', '16668.95000000', '16619.81000000', '16631.72000000', '16750.00000000', '16704.83000000', '16659.11000000', '16763.47000000', '16995.06000000', '17083.01000000', '16947.38000000', '17153.93000000', '17322.19000000', '17639.35000000', '17808.66000000', '17638.37000000', '17685.22000000', '17677.64000000', '17624.15000000', '17596.78000000', '17659.38000000', '17693.64000000', '17739.42000000', '17680.64000000', '18030.71000000', '18369.33000000', '17623.39000000', '17780.19000000', '18063.70000000', '18211.02000000', '18110.00000000', '18250.00000000', '18249.99000000', '18024.03000000', '17882.89000000', '17683.11000000', '17873.88000000', '17793.71000000', '17890.45000000', '17775.92000000']

        # graphs
        figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(100, 100), facecolor="#67676b")
        figure.add_subplot(fc="#15151c").plot(close_time, close, "-g")
        FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self).get_tk_widget().pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):  # second page
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(bg="#15151c")
        tk.Label(self, text="pg2", font=("Consolas", 40), fg="#67676b", bg="#15151c").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Return", command=lambda: app.show_frame(MainMenu)).pack()


# launch application
app = Application()
app.title("Test App")
if platform == "linux":
    app.wm_attributes("-zoomed", 1)
else:
    app.state("zoomed")
app.configure(bg="black")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: does `df["Close time"][0:50]` monotonically increase or does it also have values which increase and decrease?

Comment: @tmdavison Close time is in milliseconds and increases by the same value each time, would it help if I pasted a list of the values in my post?

Comment: Yes; It would help even more if you created a [MCVE]

Comment: @tmdavison I added an example with all the extra code taken out and a set array instead of getting latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your `close` list is a list of strings, not floats, so matplotlib is treating them as catagorical data.

```py
close = ['16691.91000000', '16690.85000000', '16779.01000000', '16825.56000000', '16695.41000000', '16713.86000000', '16713.57000000', '16806.09000000', '16690.21000000', '16678.02000000', '16573.58000000', '16668.95000000', '16619.81000000', '16631.72000000', '16750.00000000', '16704.83000000', '16659.11000000', '16763.47000000', '16995.06000000', '17083.01000000', '16947.38000000', '17153.93000000', '17322.19000000', '17639.35000000', '17808.66000000', '17638.37000000', '17685.22000000', '17677.64000000', '17624.15000000', '17596.78000000', '17659.38000000', '17693.64000000', '17739.42000000', '17680.64000000', '18030.71000000', '18369.33000000', '17623.39000000', '17780.19000000', '18063.70000000', '18211.02000000', '18110.00000000', '18250.00000000', '18249.99000000', '18024.03000000', '17882.89000000', '17683.11000000', '17873.88000000', '17793.71000000', '17890.45000000', '17775.92000000']
```

Convert the items in `close` to floats, and it should work fine. In your minimal exmaple, something like:

```py
close = [float(i) for i in close]
```

should do it.

In your original code you have a dataframe, rather than a list; you could use `df["Close"][0:50].astype(float)` as you plot the data in that case

```py
figure.add_subplot(fc="#15151c").plot(df["Close time"][0:50], df["Close"][0:50].astype(float), "-g")
```